# $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject") is not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components

i am facing an issue with navigateToSObject, it not navigating to record event i am getting correct record Id

```
navigateToTask :function(Component,Event){
    var target = event.target;
            var dataEle = target.getAttribute("data-selected-Index");
            var dataval = target.getAttribute("data-value");  
            alert(dataval);
            var recordId =dataval;
            var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
              if (navEvt){ 

              navEvt.setParams({
                 "recordId": recordId ,
                 "slideDevName": "detail"
                });

                   navEvt.fire();
                   }
                  else{
                      window.location.href = "/" + recordId;
                  }
}
```

from the above code desktop is working fine, but in SF1 it is giving blank page. 
i tired this way too still no luck [force:navigateToSObject call not working](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/86463/forcenavigatetosobject-call-not-working)

Component Code:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.tasks}" var="tsk" indexVar="index" >
                    <li class ="slds-list__item sldsListItem">
                 <a href="#void" data-selected-Index="{!index}" data-value="{!tsk.Id}" onclick="{!c.navigateToTask}">{!tsk.Subject}</a><br/>
            Type:                           {!tsk.Type}<br/>type="text" class="slds-input slds-m-top--large"
            Comments:                       {!tsk.Description}<br/>
            Due Date:                       {!tsk.CreatedDate}<br/>
            Assigned To:                    {!tsk.Owner.Name}<br/>
            Complete:
            </li> 
        </aura:iteration>
```

Comment: Share your full code ?

Comment: provided the component code.

Comment: i got the issue but not the solution, this issue with LC4VF because  it is using lightening out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer we got from salesforce is for LC4VF and for SF1 we still have to use sforce.one.navigatetosobject  and force:navigateToSObject wont work