# force:navigateToSObject not working when called from a vf page including a ltng:outApp component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

From a component included in a vf page, I need to open the record page in the SFDC CRM application ( one.app ).

I tried using force:navigateToSObject but is not working when called from a vf page including a ltng:outApp component, probably because vf page is technically in an iFrame.

It is also not possible to update the hash so when detected it opens the good record page layout ( iFrame prevent top frame url hash update )

Only solution for now is  window.top.location.href = '/one/one.app#/sObject/'+sfdcRecordId+'/view' , but :

- it provokes a full refresh of the page ( 5 seconds of snowman )
- I'm pretty sure it won't work with LockerService activated

Would anyone have a magic solution ? ( of SFDC an evol to announce ? :) )

Many thanks

Comment: Do you need to use that event? Using a traditional `a` tag should work. The one.app container will catch the navigation and go to the sObject record.

Comment: I need to use an event (or anything triggered via javascript) , I have synchronization between remote system data and SFObjects between the user click and the record layout display  ... at the moment of the click, sometimes the Record doesn't exist yet in SObjects :/

Comment: Try just using `window.location` then to navigate to `/recordId`, I believe this will get handled the same as an href.

Comment: In my question I describe that this is what I currently do, and it provokes a refresh with loading snowman. 
window.top.location.href = '/one/one.app#/sObject/'+ActionDetail.sfdcRecordId+'/view'  ; 
Do you mean something else ?

Comment: I tried window.top.location.href = '/'+sfdcRecordId ; , same result, even slower coz there is url rewriting in addition

Comment: Just posted an answer with an example that is working for me with locker service enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is something special about an anchor tag `href` that is handled by the one.app container when triggered from an iframed Visualforce page. I am not sure what this is (maybe someone could chime in if they know), but the following works for me even with locker service enabled:

```
<apex:page>

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ns.doNav()">Do Nav</a>

  <span style="display: none">
    <a id="stdNav" href="">Navigate</a>
  </span>


  <script>
      (function(ns, undefined) {

          ns.location = '/001E000001hcTcO';

          ns.doNav = function() {
             var anchorEl = document.getElementById('stdNav');
             anchorEl.href = ns.location;
             anchorEl.click();
          }
      })(window.ns = window.ns || {});

  </script>
</apex:page>
```

By updating the `href` of our hidden link then triggering the click event, the one.app container navigates to the record view page without a reload of the app. Note that depending on which browsers you need to support you may need to feature detect the `.click()` function and add some additional support there for other browser cases.

-D.S.

Comment: It works like a charm, many many many many thanks :) :)

Comment: Glad to hear that this worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

We should try the standard function - sforce.one.navigateToSObject(recordId, 'detail');

For reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).