# How to force sforce.one.navigateToSObject('...') called from Visualforce to display record page in Lightning Experience?

Tags: visualforce, lightning, navigation

I am having an issue while calling **sforce.one.navigateToSObject('...')**  method from Visualforce. It redirects me to records with given ID but it shows classical UI inside of iframe that the visualforce page was displayed, instead of what I expect - display record detail page in LEX.

To explain why I expect this behavior - all other functions that can be called on **sforce.one** object in JavaScript are interacting with Lightning Experience.

Example: **sforce.one.navigateToObjectHome('Account');** displays list of Accounts in new Lightning Experience interface.

Is it expected behavior? If Yes, how can I navigate from Visualforce page to record in Lightning Experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the problem, posted it on stackexchange, had an answer :)

[force:navigateToSObject not working when called from a vf page including a ltng:outApp component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147822/forcenavigatetosobject-not-working-when-called-from-a-vf-page-including-a-ltng)

Comment: Thanks for this. I hoped for a cleaner solution but this will make it :)

Comment: I would have liked that too but ... SFDC is SFDC :D