# How to navigate to a specific URL in Lightning with LockerService activated?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, navigation

I'm trying so hard to simply navigate to a specific URL from my Lightning custom component.

LockerService is activated, so window.location = "URL" didn't work.

I tried e.force:navigateToURL (standard event offered by the Lightning framework) but that didn't work either: When I click the button, nothing happens.

Here is my component markup:

```
<aura:component access="global" implements="force:appHostable">
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" />
    <aura:registerEvent name="navigateToURL" type="force:navigateToURL" />

    <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="{!c.goToURL}">
        Go to opportunities
    </button>

</aura:component>
```

Here is my controller code:

```
({
    doInit: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        // Nothing for now
    },
    goToURL: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        urlEvent.setParams({
          "url": "/006/o"
        });
        urlEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

Comment: Make sure you running in lightning experience.This event is handled by the one.app container. It’s supported in Lightning Experience and Salesforce1 only.

Comment: Answer here :) http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147822/forcenavigatetosobject-not-working-when-called-from-a-vf-page-including-a-ltng

Comment: Looks like you are trying to navigate to object list view, There is separate event for this [Click here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToList.htm)